# Ejecutar Stored Procedure usando Mysql y Visual

Tags: mysql, vb.net

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy desarrollando un sistema en visual basic y usando como motor de base de datos Mysql

Actualmente relizo consultas desde visual basic, pero ya quiero cambiar eso por stored procedured, pero el problema que tengo es que al llamarlo desde la aplicacion en visual no funciona, me podrian apoyar a decir que tengo mal de mi codigo

```
 Dim Conexion As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand()
    Dim ms As String

    Conexion.ConnectionString = "server=65.;database=...;user=..;password=...;"


    Conexion.Open()

    cmd = New MySqlCommand("Login", Conexion)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_usuario", usuario)
    cmd.Parameters("@_usuario").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_passsword", password)
    cmd.Parameters("@_passsword").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_mensaje", MySqlDbType.String)
    cmd.Parameters("@_mensaje").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    ms = (cmd.Parameters("@_mensaje").Value)
```

Comment: la primera pregunta es.. que quiere decir no funciona? que cosa no funciona?

Comment: ok, si mira lo que pasa es cuando mando la llamar el store desde visual me maraca error de la conexion no esta abierta

Comment: y entonces la conexion no estara abierta. te fijaste que abra correctamente?

Comment: Los errores no deben ir como imagenes, si no escritos en la misma pregunta. Y ese error no dice nada de una conexion, dice que no tenes permisos de select.

Comment: Quizás tu usuario de la base de datos no tiene el permiso para hacer una consulta de tipo SELECT (en este caso). Verificaste que puedes hacer un SELECT normal?

Comment: Si si puedo realizar consultas con ese usuario, de hecho en el sistema realizo directamente las consultas o los insert pero quise utilizar stored para reducir codigo y dejar mas limpio el codigo en visual

Comment: Podras editar tu pregunta agregando más código, de entrada en tu código no veo donde especificas el nombre del SP a usar. Para poder ayudarte mejor.